# Excel VBA - Move data based on numbering

Tags: vba, excel

I need to move data from 1 excel to another excel based on numbering format. For an example I've sample test1 excel as per below:

test1.xlsx

```
EName| Sal    | ID | Tel | Add     | Depart     | Pos      | 
------------------------------------------------------------
John | 10000  | 123| NA  | NY      | Finance    | Manager  |
------------------------------------------------------------
  1  |    5   |  2 |     |         |    3       |   4      |
```

Column arranged in numbers. I need to move my data to another excel in this case test2 and paste in numbering format.

test.xlsx

```
Name  | ID | Department |  Level     |Position | Salary |
  1   |  2 |     3      |            |   4     |   5    |
John  | 123| Fiinanace  |    NA      |Manager  | 10000  |
```

Value for each column identified by the numbers.
How do I achieve this. Any advice/references is highly appreciated. Thanks

```
Sub startGenerateExcel()
Path1 = Range("F4").Value
Path2 = Range("F6").Value

Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngDest As Range
Dim colNum As Integer
Dim colDest As Integer
Dim cl As Range

Set wbSource = Workbooks(Path1)
Set wbDest = Workbooks(Path2)

Set rngSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G3") 'Modify as needed
Set rngDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F3") 'Modify as needed

For Each cl In rngSource.Rows(2)
    colNum = cl.Offset(1, 0).Value
    colDest = Application.Match(colNum, rngDest.Rows(3), False)
    rngDest.Cells(2, colDest).Value = cl.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use formulas in the new sheet that refer back to the original sheet?  The formulas in column 1 of the new sheet will refer to the name column in the old sheet, those in column 2 will refer to the id column, etc. After you've copied the formulas down to the bottom of your data, just copy the formula block and paste it in place as values. If for whatever reason you have to do it in VBA, think "arrays".

Comment: @chuff I not allowed to edit the output file. The output file shouldn't contains any formula or any macros. I'm creating another excel file where the user need to provide path for the input file.

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested but fundamentally shoudl work. I use the `Match` function to do this sort of thing all the time.  You will have to tweak it for your specific purposes, i.e., assuming your tables are more than just 3 rows, etc.

```
Sub TransferValuesUsingMatch()

Dim wbSource as Workbook
Dim wbDest as Workbook
Dim rngSource as Range
Dim rngDest as Range
Dim colNum as Integer
Dim colDest as Integer
Dim cl as Range

Set wbSource = Workbooks("test1.xlsx") 'Assumes the workbook is already open
Set wbDest = Workbooks("test.xlsx") 'Assumes the workbook is already open
Set rngSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G3") 'Modify as needed
Set rngDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F3") 'Modify as needed

For each cl in rngSource.Rows(2) 
    colNum = cl.Offset(1,0).Value
    colDest = Application.Match(colNum, rngDest.Rows(3), False)
    rngDest.Cells(2,colDest).Value = cl.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Run Time Error - Subscript out of range. Added code in my question

Comment: Which line raises the error?  Do both files have a "Sheet1" which contains the data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to rearrange the rows too or if you examples just have the numbers for illustration, but I'm assuming you just want to move columns of data based on the names in the header row.

I like to pull data out of Excel sheets and put that data into an array. Do something to the data, and then put it back into an Excel sheet. It's faster than working with in the cells and it will work well in this case. See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx for some sample code on how to do that.

You can put each column into its own array and then use the values in position (1, 1) to rearrange them in the destination file. You can adjust that position to suite your needs if there is a different row that contains the ordering information.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

It reads the data from the "old" worksheet into an array, writes the rearranged data into a new array, and then assigns the values of the new array to the "new" worksheet.

```
Sub CopyAndRearrange()

    Dim oldWkb As Workbook, newWkb As Workbook
    Dim oldRange As Range, newRange As Range
    Dim oldArr(), newArr()

    'Assume data are in Sheet1 in oldWkb and need to go to Sheet1 in newWkb
    'and that both workbooks are open
    Set oldWkb = Workbooks("aWkb.xlsm")
    Set newWkb = Workbooks("anotherWkb.xlsm")
    Set oldRange = oldWkb.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:G11")
    Set newRange = newWkb.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:F11")
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

'   Assume data have fixed, known dimensions
    ReDim oldArray(1 To 10, 1 To 7)
    oldArray = oldRange
    ReDim newArray(1 To 10, 1 To 6)
    For i = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 6
            Select Case j
                Case 1
                    newArray(i, 1) = oldArray(i, 1)  '1->1
                Case 2
                    newArray(i, 6) = oldArray(i, 2)  '2->6
                    Debug.Print newArray(i, 6)
                Case 3
                    newArray(i, 2) = oldArray(i, 3)  '3->2                      
                Case 4
                    newArray(i, 3) = oldArray(i, j + 2)  '6->3
                Case 5
                    newArray(i, 5) = oldArray(i, j + 2)  '7->5
                Case 6
                    newArray(i, 4) = "NA"                'NA->4
            End Select
        Next j
    Next i
    newRange.Value = newArray

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I your code, replace `For ... Next` with:

```
For Each cl In rngSource.Rows 'Handle whole row at once!
    rngDest.Cells(cl.Row, 1).Resize(, 6) = Array(cl.Cells(, 1), cl.Cells(1, 3), cl.Cells(1, 6), Empty, cl.Cells(1, 7), cl.Cells(1, 2))
Next
```